# How do I dynamically create a named_route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I currently have this in my ApplicationController

```
def account_path
  eval "#{current_user.type.downcase}_account_path"
end
```

I use it for redirects, etc.  But I also want to use it in the view (for link_to's etc).  Is this is a legit case to share code between the controller and view to keep it DRY even though it breaks MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I'd say that's a legitimate re-use. The `helper_method` call is there for a reason so:

```
helper_method :account_path
```

will make this available to your views too.

If you prefer not to use `eval` you could do:

```
def account_path
  self.send("#{current_user.type.downcase}_account_path")
end
```

as the `_path` method is interpreted as a method on the controller.